# Run python interactive console as a subprocess in swift with sending commands and receiving results after launched

Tags: python, swift, macos, tty, pty

I'm making my first steps in macOS app development.
I'm trying to write an app on Swift that would keep python interactive console open.
Sometimes I would like to send to python commands and return the results back to swift, but not closing python to keep all variables for the next command I will send.

Is there any way to do that?

As far as I understand, I can't use the `Process()` because the input pipe automatically closes when I run the task.

I probably need to use pseudo terminals with pty and tty, but I don't fully understand the idea and where to learn about it. (or, maybe, I'm wrong and there is another way)

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to use python code from swift, I would strongly advise you to avoid using this method. It is very bug prone and potentially limiting and inefficient. You better use some wrapper of the python-c-api, or write some small server in python to receive requests from swift.

If you still want to do that, an easy way to go about it would be to use python itself to spawn python inside a pty:

`python -c "import pty, sys; pty.spawn(sys.argv[1:])" python`

This will start a python console that reads and writes to stdio instead of of `/dev/tty`.